# Media queries - not responding on devices

Tags: css, media-queries, media

```
@media screen (max-width: 750px) or (screen and (max-width: 750px) (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),(min-resolution: 192dpi)) {  
        div.body, div.body div.links, div.body div.links div, div.footer, div.footer div {      
            display: block !important;      
            overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

another version

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {  
        div.body, div.body div.links, div.body div.links div, div.footer, div.footer div, table, td, tr{      
            display: block !important;      
            overflow: hidden !important;
        }
```

Hi all,

Above is my media queries for my code. This code is for a news letter and for some reason the media queries will have no effect went sent to a mobile device. Is there something that I am missing in the media queries? The phone I am using to test is an iPhone XR.

Thank you so much in advance!

Dom

Comment: That looks like an overly complex media query to me. What do you mean when you say "[when] sent to a mobile device?" Do you mean when the site is pulled up in a web view in an app? Opened in a mobile browser? If the latter, which mobile browser(s) have you tried? What are you trying to accomplish with the `or`? Not to mention it looks like you aren't properly closing your rules with `}`.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for responding so quickly. This is an email sent from Thunderbird to a campus community. So, students can pull it up on any device or any site/email client. We use Gmail for our email service. I added the other media query I used as well to the question

Comment: @Dom you can't use media queries on emails

Comment: you missing `}` at the end.

Comment: you missing `}` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove !important and add a }.Also use @media all like this

```
@media all and (max-width: 750px) {  
    div.body, div.body div.links, div.body div.links div, div.footer, div.footer div, table, td, tr{      
        display: block;      
        overflow: hidden;
    } 
}
```

did it work?

Comment: I removed the !important and added the }. This results in the same issue as before. The process for these emails are "copy code from Dreamweaver -> place in a CSS inliner -> paste into a Thunderbird email using insert HTML".

Comment: I didn't understand the process.What is this process for?

Comment: This is an email newsletter that is going to a campus community. We need the newsletter to be able to change design with the @media query. The process is for how we send the emails to the students.

Comment: Ok.I understood.

Comment: I'm very happy that my answer helped you:)

Answer (score 0):

In both your queries you seem to be missing a `}`

```
@media screen (max-width: 750px) or (screen and (max-width: 750px) (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),(min-resolution: 192dpi)) {  
  div.body, div.body div.links, div.body div.links div, div.footer, div.footer div {      
     display: block !important;      
     overflow: hidden !important;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {  
   div.body, div.body div.links, div.body div.links div, div.footer, div.footer div, table, td, tr{      
      display: block !important;      
      overflow: hidden !important;
   }
}
```

Comment: When I added that missing }, it turned the code into what it should look like on mobile and did not respond when turned back into its normal resolution. It stayed as its mobile format when passing the 750px threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Please put this code and check.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 751px) {
   div.body, div.body div.links, div.body div.links div, div.footer, div.footer div, table, td, tr{      
        display: block !important;      
        overflow: hidden !important;
    } 
}
```

And also check your header in html.
Is meta tag is there or not.
If not then please put it in your head.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: I added what you have posted as the @media query. The issues are still persisting. Could it be an issue with Gmail or the inliner? What is weird is that the mobile version of the email newsletter is showing in Dreamweaver even when it is screen is past the media threshold.

Comment: If you write down media query for mobile then please check this : https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/mobile/